# Doing a histogram from two sets of values (Julia 0.6.4)

Tags: plot, julia, histogram

I'm new to Julia and know some about it but I was recently asked to create a histogram out of two 70-element array float elements, so, for example:

I have two lists of elements, say:

```
x = [1.3, 4.6, 7.8, 10.4, 200.4, 1000.42, 1111.1, 1234.56]
y = [0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 7, 32, 0]
```

How can I make a Histogram out of this?

Comment: How about http://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/empirical.html#Histograms-1?

Comment: Also see [StatPlots](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatPlots.jl) (which uses [Plots](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl), the primary plotting API)

Comment: The problem is that I don't completely understand the variables....
I'll try to understand it though, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use PyPlot for this (please not that it should be installed first)

```
 using PyPlot
 PyPlot.plt[:hist]([x,y],bins=8);
```

Michel's comment below is right - you did not explain what is the data and it does not seem like typical data for histogram.

If `x` holds bar location and `y` bar heights you could do

```
p = PyPlot.plt[:bar](x,y,width=25);
```

Yet another option (this will show `x` values as bar labels:

```
PyPlot.plt[:cla]()  #remember to clear the plot :-)
PyPlot.plt[:bar](1:length(y),y);
PyPlot.plt[:xticks](1:length(y),x);
```

Comment: Anyway to add an " xlim=(x,y) " ??

Comment: `PyPlot.plt[:xlim]()` returns the `x` limit  `PyPlot.plt[:xlim]([1,10])` sets the `x` limit to be between `1` and `10`

Answer (score 1):

Those variables, by the look of it, don't look like something you'd run `histogram` on. They look like the bin centers of the histogram, and the count of data points in each. As such, it essentially already might be a histogram.

If you want to plot a histogram from edges and counts, you'd use a `bar` plot (not a `histogram` plot, which involves binning your data into a histogram and plotting it).

But, your variables are not evenly spaced, and `y` are not floats, though you write they are. Are these the correct numbers?

Comment: Nono, these were just for example, I've two list of 70-elements each, both of which have floats in each array.

Comment: And do you want both histograms to appear in the same plot window?